# $A^2 + A + I_n = 0 \implies$ matrix $A$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to proof that if
$A^2 + A + I_n = 0$ then matrix $A$ is invertible.

I can see why $A^2 + A$ is invertible, but can't find a way to proof it on $A$.

Comment: The usual terminology is "A is invertible" (and not reversable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Ax=0$, then $0=(A^2+A+I_n)x=I_nx=x$, hence $ker(A)=\{0\}$.

Conclusion ?

Comment: I would add general conclusion that if only $p(A)=0$ with non-zero part  $I_n$ then $A$ must be invertible.

Comment: Yes, if $ p(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x$ and $p(A)+I_n=0$, then $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Why the downvote? ?

Comment: I upvoted both answers, they seem to be very good.  I'm also very interested what weaknesses someone noticed in the reasoning about kernel ..

Answer (score 4):

$I_n=-A(A+I_n)$, hence $1= \det(I_n)= \det(-A)\det(A+I_n)=(-1)^n \det(A) \det(A+I_n).$

This gives $ \det(A) \ne 0$.

Comment: And more explicitly, $A^{-1}=-A-I_n$.

Comment: @Dietrich: $A=-I_n$ doe not satisfy the equation $A^2 + A + I_n = 0.$

Comment: @Fred Good point!

Answer (score 4):

The inverse is $-(A+I)$, since by direct calculation

$$-(A+I)A=-A^2-A=I.$$

Comment: This is the best answer here. I have allowed myself to reformat. Undo if you want.

Answer (score 2):

To show that any square matrix A is **invertible**, you need to show that there *exists* a square matrix $A^{-1}$ (called the **inverse** of A) such that $AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A = I_n $. That's the definition of a matrix being invertible.

Now, we can use the equation $A^2 + A + I_n = O_n$ to find a potential candidate for the inverse $A^{-1}$ such that the equation $AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A = I_n $ holds. Let us solve for $I_n$:

$A^2 + A + I_n = O_n$ ⇒ $I_n = -A^2 - A$ ⇒ $I_n = A(-A - I_n)$

Here, we have our candidate inverse matrix, which is just $A^{-1} = (-A - I_n)$. Now, you must show that it satisfies the equation $AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A = I_n$.

Let $A^{-1} = -A - I_n$. Then $AA^{-1} = A(-A - I_n) = -A^2 - AI_n = -A^2 - A = -(A^2 + A) = I_n$

Similarly, $A^{-1}A = (-A - I_n)A = -A^2 - I_{n}A = -A^2 - A = I_n$.

By the definition, A is invertible.